# Flatpak app can’t open links

Tags: ubuntu, d-bus, flatpak, links

I don’t know much about flatpak, so not sure where to look for.

I can’t open links from thunderbird flatpak to firefox flatpak.

I’ve looked around it seems that it should be an problem with *portals*. Yet, when I try to debug with `flatpak run --log-session-bus org.gnome.Maps`, the logs don’t seem to show anything wrong with portals when clicking on a link in the app  (at least I don’t see it):

```
C63: -> org.freedesktop.DBus call org.freedesktop.DBus.AddMatch at /org/freedesktop/DBus
C64: -> org.freedesktop.DBus call org.freedesktop.DBus.AddMatch at /org/freedesktop/DBus
C65: -> org.freedesktop.DBus call org.freedesktop.DBus.StartServiceByName at /org/freedesktop/DBus
B40: <- org.freedesktop.DBus return from C63
B41: <- org.freedesktop.DBus return from C64
B42: <- org.freedesktop.DBus return from C65
C66: -> org.freedesktop.DBus call org.freedesktop.DBus.GetNameOwner at /org/freedesktop/DBus
B43: <- org.freedesktop.DBus return from C66
C67: -> :1.80 call org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties.GetAll at /org/freedesktop/portal/desktop
B1171: <- :1.80 return from C67
C68: -> :1.80 call org.freedesktop.portal.OpenURI.OpenURI at /org/freedesktop/portal/desktop
B1172: <- :1.80 return from C68
B1175: <- :1.80 signal org.freedesktop.portal.Request.Response at /org/freedesktop/portal/desktop/request/1_715/gtk2129782386
```

I don’t get it. Thoughts?

My OS:

```
6.2.0-36-generic #37~22.04.1-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Mon Oct  9 15:34:04 UTC 2 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

flatpak version:

```
Flatpak 1.12.7
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For my specific case, it was just a stupid thing.

I had the regular .deb package of Firefox installed as well on the system. Hence, when clicking a URL, it was trying to open with the .deb Firefox.

For some reason, it did not open the .deb Firefox and open the link, which is weird. For some reason, the .deb Firefox did not show up in the app menu, but was installed. I verified it with `dpkg -S /usr/share/applications/firefox.desktop` which gave `firefox: /usr/share/applications/firefox.desktop`.

Anyways, just in case, do `sudo apt remove firefox`, and now it should work (might have to set the flatpak version as the default browser in the settings).

Although that solved the issue of URL, it does not solve the whole issue of opening documents (received in thunderbird flatpak for example) in another flatpak application (like ONLYOFFICE). I still haven’t figured that out.

I’ll mark this as accepted answer for now. If anyone knows how to figure out the other issue, that’d be great.

Comment: Which distribution are you on?

Comment: I am having the same issue on Fedora 39 Silverblue with Firefox Flatpak